# How can I set Swagger to ignore @Suspended AsyncResponse in @Asynchronous jax-rs bean methods?

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, swagger

Swagger-Core seems to interpret the @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse member as request body param. This is clearly not intended nor the case.

I would like to tell swagger-core to ignore this parameter and to exclude it from the api-docs. Any ideas?

This is what my code looks like:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/coffee")
@Api(value = "/coffee", description = "The coffee service.")
public class CoffeeService
{
    @Inject
    Event<CoffeeRequest> coffeeRequestListeners;

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get Coffee.", notes = "Get tasty coffee.")
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Beans not found."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Something exceptional happend.")})
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Asynchronous
    public void makeCoffee( @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,

                             @ApiParam(value = "The coffee type.", required = true)
                             @QueryParam("type")
                             String type)
    {
        coffeeRequestListeners.fire(new CoffeeRequest(type, asyncResponse));
    }
}
```

---

#### Update: Solution based on Answer

```
public class InternalSwaggerFilter implements SwaggerSpecFilter
{
    @Override
    public boolean isOperationAllowed(Operation operation, ApiDescription apiDescription, Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap, Map<String, String> stringStringMap, Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap2) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isParamAllowed(Parameter parameter, Operation operation, ApiDescription apiDescription, Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap, Map<String, String> stringStringMap, Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap2) {
        if( parameter.paramAccess().isDefined() && parameter.paramAccess().get().equals("internal") )
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
FilterFactory.setFilter(new InternalSwaggerFilter());
```

---

#### Revised Example Code Fragment

```
...
@Asynchronous
public void makeCoffee( @Suspended @ApiParam(access = "internal") final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,...)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use filters.
Here is an example https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/269

Could be coded in java too.

Answer (score 9):

Fast forward to 2016 where swagger-springmvc is replaced by [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) (documentation is available [here](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/)). Ignoring paramaters is available in springfox, but is for some reason not documented:

**Alternative 1**: Globally ignore types or annotated types with `.ignoredParameterTypes(...)` in Docket configuration:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .host(reverseProxyHost)
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .directModelSubstitute(OffsetDateTime.class, String.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(Duration.class, String.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
        .forCodeGeneration(true)
        .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, newArrayList(
            new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                .code(200).message("Success").build()
            )
        .apiInfo(myApiInfo())
        .ignoredParameterTypes(AuthenticationPrincipal.class, Predicate.class, PathVariable.class)
        .select()
            .apis(withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
            .paths(any())
        .build();
}
```

**Alternativ 2**: Use `@ApiIgnore`-annotation to ignore single parameter in method:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "User details")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public MyUser getUser(@ApiIgnore @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUser user) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This answer is Spring specific.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue with the same technique that you use, but with a different approach. Instead of marking it as internal I just ignore all the params with the type AsyncResponse, that way I don't need to update the code in all methods to add the access modifier.

```
public class CustomSwaggerSpecFilter implements SwaggerSpecFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean isOperationAllowed(Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map<String, List<String>> params, Map<String, String> cookies,
            Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isParamAllowed(Parameter parameter, Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map<String, List<String>> params,
            Map<String, String> cookies, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
        if(parameter.dataType().equals("AsyncResponse")) { // ignoring AsyncResponse parameters
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

That works better for me.

Comment: Which version do you use. For me there is no such method `dataType()`?

Comment: Sorry, this was long ago, don't remember what version it was, no longer working with that code base. I think the Swagger APIs have changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to do this.

```
@Bean
public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin mvPluginOverride() {
    SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin swaggerSpringMvcPlugin = new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(apiInfo());
    swaggerSpringMvcPlugin.ignoredParameterTypes(PagedResourcesAssembler.class, Pageable.class);
    return swaggerSpringMvcPlugin;
}
```