# Swagger-play2 - hiding internal parameters

Tags: playframework, swagger, play-framework-2.7, swagger-play2

I have configured swagger-play2 library version 1.7.1 (for play framework version 2.7) and have it up and running successfully. Our controller methods have an additional input: `Http.Request request` which is passed across the application for some logging and monitoring purposes. I need to hide this from the swagger specs, tried using `@ApiParam(hidden = true)` but it still shows up in specs. Is this flag not working as expected? how do I hide the input in this case? I'd like to know whether `@ApiParam(hidden = true)` has worked for anyone with `swagger-play2` plugin, not with Spring.

Thanks.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22812365/113116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a parameter in swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812365/how-to-hide-a-parameter-in-swagger)

Comment: Thanks @Helen @Valerii-rusakov. As I have mentioned in the question, using `@ApiParam(hidden = true)` didn't work. And it looks like @ApiIgnore is not there for swagger-play2.