# Hiding unimportant getter methods from swagger UI in Java

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have two fields in my class `startDate` and `endDate` of `LocalDateTime`. Internally, these need to be returned as `Optional<ZonedDateTime>`, while in the query they are provided as LocalDateTimes.

```
@ApiModel
public class SearchQuery {

    private static final ZoneId UTC_TIMEZONE = ZoneId.of("UTC");

    @ApiParam(value = "Start date and time of the requested time frame.", example = "2019-06-01T12:30", defaultValue = "0000-01-01T00:00")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @ApiParam(value = "End date and time of the requested time frame.", example = "2019-06-30T23:59", defaultValue = "9999-12-31T23:59")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
        return this.startDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEndDate() {
        return this.endDate;
    }

    public Optional<ZonedDateTime> getStartDateWithTimezone() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(startDate)
            .map(date -> date.atZone(UTC_TIMEZONE));
    }

    public Optional<ZonedDateTime> getEndDateWithTimezone() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(endDate)
            .map(date -> date.atZone(UTC_TIMEZONE));
    }
}
```

Swagger (Springfox v2.9.2) now shows the needed fields but also `endDateWithTimezone.present` and `startDateWithTimezone.present`, which are of course both not needed as parameters:

[image]

I have been trying for some time now to find ways to hide these from my swagger documentation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple in the end.

You have to use the annotation `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)` directly on the getter you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be a duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677559/8932643

Ronny Shibley answers:

> For Parameters
>
> ```
> public void getApi(@ApiIgnore String param){}
>
> @ApiModelProperty(hidden="true")
> public String paramInsideClass
> ```

Comment: No, unfortunately, it is not. As I said, I need `startDate` and `endDate`. If I use `@ApiModelProperty(hidden="true")` on the field, I won't get anything in Swagger. I would like to use it on the methods that return the Optional, but that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

rename `getStartDateWithTimezone` to `findStartDateWithTimezone`